# Hybrid button/combo box UI control in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, button, user-interface, combobox

There's a kind of hybrid UI pattern that is part button, part drop-down list.  If the user clicks on the displayed action, then that action gets invoked as per a normal button; if they click on the arrow part, then the user can select from other available actions as with a combo box.

Two questions:

- is there a name for this hybrid button/list UI pattern?
- is there a native or 3rd-party implementation of this in Silverlight?

Comment: Whenever I have implimented this "control" it has always been a Button with the Upper and Lower-Right corner radius set to 0 and right margin of 0 with a separate Drop-Down List with the Upper and Lower Left corner radius 0 and left margin of 0. I have not yet seen it as a stock control in any framework.

Comment: @EtherDragon what would you call it?  *ComboButton* maybe?

Comment: Yea, that might work. =) Also, looks like Telerik has a control that does just that, (Commercial product though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telerik call it a [Split Button](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Buttons/SplitButton)